# Communicate with a device over wifi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I have been asked if it's possible to create a windows app that can communicate with a [device](https://www.empirbus.com/wp-content/uploads/EmpirBus-Connect-50-User-manual-Ver-1.33.BW_.pdf) that has its own wireless so you can connect and control it from there. Is it possible to create a react app with electron so that the app can be built on a windows pc or mac to communicate and control this device? I can't seem to find any info anywhere on how to do this from the React side of things, I can only find [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wifi) from node.

Can anyone point me in a better direction?

Comment: React is just UX; you can use React to interact with arbitrary devices over arbitrary comms. If you can connect to it with node then you can control that connection with electron and react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much familiar with your device.but if you have a udp connection listening and forwarding with a port and ip then you can listen to that udp from you node datagram module (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/dgram.html) , then can control the device as well receive data from device to and from

Comment: Please include the relevant section from the link that you point to in your answer. This helps in case the link becomes unavailable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, a huge help :)